# How far did Forrest Gump run?

Tags: forrest-gump

One day, Forrest just started running. He ran for 3 years, 2 months, 14 days and 16 hours. He slept, when he needed to, he ate when he was hungry and he went to, you know, when he needed to.

How far did he run during this time?

Comment: Given that he was supposed to be mentally challenged, that all he did was eat, sleep, and runm and that he "just felt like it."  It seems unlikely that he had any reason (if even the ability) to count the days minutes and hours.  Also, he had to  use an ATM frequently unless people gave him food for free.  Finally, he was running slow enough for a lot of groupies to keep up with him.

Comment: You forgot that when he had to go, he went.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Based on different information given in the film and in the script and on filming locations, the site Centives [calculated](http://www.centives.net/S/2012/forrest-gumps-running-route/) that Forrest Gump ran **15248 miles (24539 km)**, crossing the United States five times, before he decided to go home.

[image: map of USA showing where Forrest ran]

Another estimation [can be found](http://theweek.com/articles/457759/could-forrest-gump-have-possibly-survived-epic-run) on theweek.com. It totals **19024 miles (30616 km)**. The route of the first two years looks like this

[image: Another USA map showing Forrest's route]

Which is close to the route shown in the film:

[image: still from the film, with television showing newscaster with Forrest's route displayed behind her]

Comment: Given the time he took and the estimated distance from the source, that makes for a rather meager (in terms of running) 0.8735 km/h average speed, or about 21 km (13 miles) per day. Over the course of 3 years this is, of course, quite a distance.

Comment: @xLeitix I guess it's behind the J marker.

Comment: @Ian They address this a little bit in the linked article on theweek.com.

Comment: @Ian I am tempted to ask a follow-up question whether this is in any way realistic.

Comment: @xLeitix you might get a good answer for that on https://sports.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @xLeitix [Terry Fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terry_Fox) averaged 23 miles per day and he only had one leg. So it is probably realistic in that it is plausible for Gump to run that much. Though another runner could have run more.

Comment: How come neither of those estimates includes the return trip?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Did he run back home? Maybe he took a flight or used a car.

Comment: @xLeitix Many dedicated runners and marathoners train 10-15 miles per day year-round for years on end in their spare time. Cross-USA record attempts cover 60+ miles per day. If anything, these estimates might be unrealistically low -- what was he doing the rest of the time if only running 3-5 hours per day?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft He stopped running one day. Then he says, how long he‘s been running so the way back does not count.

Comment: The distance probably could have been a lot longer, assuming that he didn’t pay a whole lot of attention to the routes he was taking or whether they were the best way to reach wherever next was.

Comment: @xLeitix On Strava (the app I use to record my running and swimming) there are people on the leaderboards with over 5,400 miles ran so far this year alone (and we're only in August). Going off that, doing 19,000 miles over 3 years is definitely achievable, but, would still be considered an incredible feat by most.

Comment: @usul Much of the territory he chose to run **is not flat**. You can't run meridian lines, you have to run the surface.  West Virginians say it would be America's 3rd largest state if you ironed it out flat, and it's not even in real mountains!

Comment: @Harper Except the other states would grow if you ironed them, too. Also, even if you only ironed WV, I find the claim hard to believe: even a 45% slope is only about 40% longer than the line it projects onto flat ground, so ironing shouldn't make much difference.

Comment: If both estimates differ by more than 5000km, you might not want to give distances with km precision.

Answer (score 19):

This is a trick question because either he lied about how long he run or was unintentionally confused.

Forrest supposedly started running when Jimmy Carter collapsed (that possible heart attack scare) while running his six mile race in October (I think it was on the 1st), 1979; and he stopped when Ronald Reagan assassination attempt took place on March 21, 1981.  That's not even one and a half a year, and considerably shorter than 3 years, 2 months, 14 days and 16 hours.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, unless it's actually inaccurate.  I don't remember the film well enough to tell.

Comment: @Wildcard the start date is supported by the same source that the other, highly upvoted answer uses. As for the end date, going by Wikipedia, the end date is almost certainly in or before 1981 (Wiki says: 'Back to the present (the "present" in the film being 1981, as seen from a car and on a bus, and televised footage of Ronald Reagan's escape from assassination), ...'). But even if Gump lied or misremembered the duration, IMO that doesn't affect how the question of distance should be answered.

Comment: @muru Answering the questions depends on a host of suppositions so there is no logical answer that all will agree on - you might just as well argue instead over the maximum number of angels that might fit on the tip of a pin.  Such problems then, rather than being dismissed, automatically assume existence of angels in physical forms.  

Then should you divide that distance into 3 years, 2 months, 14 days and 16 hours or into around 18 months?  With the latter, the average daily distance more than doubles, turning the overall distance into the impossible angels.  The book author's error.

Comment: This doesn't answer how far Gump ran, only for how long.